# Open Search Description (aperte tab para pesquisar)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

Eu fiz um sistema de ramais para a empresa e queria implementar neste sistema o "aperte guia(tab) para pesquisar" que vejo em vários sites. 
Já fiz de todas as maneiras possíveis e não consigo fazer aparecer isso.

o código xml que eu uso está assim:
[image: Código xml]

Já me certifiquei que o link está certo.

Aqui é o exemplo do que eu quero que aconteça:

[image: Tab to search (aperte guia para pesquisar)]

E por fim, um print do sistema, com o exemplo de pesquisa na url

[image: Sistema]

E outra dúvida que eu tenho, esse OpenSearchDescription funciona no localhost, ou somente em sites na internet?

Answer (score 1):

É preciso colocar o caminho do XML na *tag* `<head>` da sua aplicação:

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/OpenSearch.xml") %>"
        rel="search"
        title="Pesquisa no Meu Sistema de Ramais"
        type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" />
    ...
</head>
```

> E outra dúvida que eu tenho, esse OpenSearchDescription funciona no localhost, ou somente em sites na internet?

É para funcionar em ambos.